# Z-index works only in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, z-index

I have a live website 
http://getfreekidsmusic.com/christmassongs2
and

http://getfreekidsmusic.com/christmassongs1/

I've wanted logo to be on top of the .content div. mainly I use the Google Chrome DT because I prefer it over the FF fire-bug, but I have FF as well, in chrome z-index and other css render the way I want to but in Firefox there is no z-index and items are displayed normally as there is no index given.

Anyway I've tested it in browser stack and it showed me that whole website needs a little work to be truly cross browser.
I've developed css on my own and then absorb bootstrap that's why the css file is such a mess, currently I am rewriting and tweaking the css but I have no idea why the z-index doesn't work outside of Chrome.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with your site using firebug for FF and the problem isn't the z-index, but the wrapping div of the logo. When I changed these properties as below FF worked:

```
#logo img {
margin-bottom: -100px;
position: static;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: that worked, but I don't know why it cannot be achieved same as in Google Chrome. 
but still there is a bug when you will navigate to subpage, e.g. About Us in chrome it looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

since we are without any code snippets - and i've seen z-index working in firefox, i looked for a tut for you.

found this via google:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

> Although z-index is not a difficult property to understand, due to
>   false assumptions it can cause confusion for beginning developers.
>   This confusion occurs because z-index will only work on an element
>   whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or
>   relative.